# Accidently deleted wchar.h in ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was working with some files in usr/lib and usr/include where I accidently deleted wchar.h header file of ubuntu. Is there any way by which I can retrieve the file back or get the file online?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dpkg -S wchar.h` will tell you which installed package contains a file with said name. Once you identified the matching occurrence/path—which you can provide as well as part of the previous query if you already know it in advance—, just reinstall said package (e.g., using `apt install --reinstall libc6-dev`).